# Good php+mysql system for managing library of books (book catalogue/database software)

Tags: php, mysql, library, system

Anyone know a good web based system to manage libraries (of books)?

It's like a book catalogue/database software, but with web interface, because I want people to be able do searches / queries in the web system.

I prefer systems based on PHP and MySQL, because in general they are easier to install and administer, but others are also welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "medium libraries"?

Comment: If you're talking about a CMS (Content  Management System), then we need to know what sort of content you're planning on putting up.

In any case, the CMS you get doesn't effect the performance of your 'libraries.' You should look into web hosts that have a lot of dedicated storage space and never goes down. MySQL is a good choice.

Comment: @Lese majeste : Library of books, of medium size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this question I found the answers I needed.

https://superuser.com/questions/65082/web-based-library-management-foss-application

As the user heavyd said, the only two viable options I found were [Koha](http://koha.org/) and [Evergreen](http://www.open-ils.org/).

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 has a [library plugin](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/sf_books/current/) which may be what you're looking for.

I think I came across some other web platforms aimed at actual libraries, but those may not be suited to your needs. However, I'll add them later if I can find them again.